# Save email attachments to corresponding hard drive folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that scans a subfolder for emails with pdf attachments and saves them to a specific folder on my shared hard drive.

I want the end folder to change depending on the filename of the pdf attachment.

For example
I receive an email attachment containing the number 033000.001.1.
I have a corresponding folder in my shared hard drive under that number.
When I receive an email with that numbered attachment, the pdf file goes to that folder in my shared drive.
An attachment with another number goes to another corresponding folder.

It is a plus to make the code create the new folder with the number as it is saved.

```vb
Sub SaveAttachmentsToFolder()
    ' This Outlook macro checks a named subfolder in the Outlook Inbox
    ' (here the "Sales Reports" folder) for messages with attached
    ' files of a specific type (here file with an "xls" extension)
    ' and saves them to disk. Saved files are timestamped. The user
    ' can choose to view the saved files in Windows Explorer.
    ' NOTE: make sure the specified subfolder and save folder exist
    ' before running the macro.
    On Error GoTo SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Palo Park")
    i = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Subm from Arch folder.", vbInformation, _
          "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            ' Check filename of each attachment and save if it has "pdf" extension
            If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
                ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                FileName = "S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect\" & _
                  Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item
    ' Show summary message
    If i > 0 Then
        varResponse = MsgBox("I found " & i & " attached files." _
          & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect folder." _
          & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to view the files now?" _
          , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
        ' Open Windows Explorer to display saved files if user chooses
        If varResponse = vbYes Then
            Shell "Explorer.exe /e,S:\1- Job Files - Active\# 3034 - BHP Palo Park\07 - Submittals\Submittals from Architect\", vbNormalFocus
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

' Clear memory
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    ' Handle Errors
    SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
    & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
    & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on any/all aspects of your code, you can present it to reviewers on [codereview.se]. See their [how-to-ask page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is `033000.001.1` the attachment name or part of the attachment?

Comment: The number 033000.001.1 would be part of the attachment name.

Answer (score -1):

Try to follow the sample below . . .

Set a reference to Outlook and copy/paste the code in a standard module

```
1) Go to the VBA editor, Alt -F11
2) Tools>References in the Menu bar
3) Place a Checkmark before Microsoft Outlook ? Object Library
    ? is the Outlook version number
4) Insert>Module
5) Paste the code (two macros) in this module
6) Alt q to close the editor
7) Save the file

Sub Test()
'Arg 1 = Folder name of folder inside your Inbox
'Arg 2 = File extension, "" is every file
'Arg 3 = Save folder, "C:\Users\Ron\test" or ""
'        If you use "" it will create a date/time stamped folder for you in your "Documents" folder
'        Note: If you use this "C:\Users\Ron\test" the folder must exist.

    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "xls", ""

End Sub
```

Note: You not have to change the code in the macro below. But you can change Item.SenderName to ReceivedTime in the save line like Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mmm-dd")

When you do that it will put the ReceivedTime before each file name instead of the SenderName

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding the code you suggested. How do I add this to the code I already have?